# When the lazy column list item is long, the Keyboard covers the Textfield in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

- I have a lazy list of text fields in jetpack compose (around 10 OutlineTextField())
- The last few text fields are hidden by the keyboard
- How can I move those lower text fields above the keyboard? Thank you

Comment: Post your code pls

Comment: did u fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Add this on themes.xml in the style that your activity is using:

adjustResize|stateVisible

or android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" in your manifest on activity that contain your list

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the `accompanist-insets` dependencies

```
implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-insets:<version>"
// If using insets-ui
implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-insets-ui:<version>"
```

Then use the `ProvideWindowInsets(windowInsetsAnimationsEnabled = true)` as showin in following code in your MainActivity.

```
setContent {
        ProvideWindowInsets(windowInsetsAnimationsEnabled = true) {
            MyApplicationTestTheme {
               //your content goes here
            }
        }
 }
```

For more details check out the [documentation](https://google.github.io/accompanist/insets/#ime-animations)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to remove the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` from the manifest and keyboard stopped jumping around after that.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following steps to get the desired output:

1. In the manifest file add the following:

```
<manifest 
    ...
    ...>

    <application
        ...
        ...
        ...>

        <activity
            ...
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            ...>
            ...
            ...
            ...
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

2. In your composable with `LazyColumn` get reference to the `LazyListState` and then observe the view tree like the following `ScrollOnKeyboardVisibility()` function.

```
@Composable
fun UI(){
    val lazyColumnState = rememberLazyListState()
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    Column {
        LazyColumn (
            state = lazyColumnState
        ){
            ...
            ...
            ...
        }
        ...
        ...
        ...    
    }
    ScrollOnKeyboardVisibility(lazyColumnState, coroutineScope)
}


@Composable
fun ScrollOnKeyboardVisibility(lazyListState: LazyListState, coroutineScope: CoroutineScope) {
    val currentView = LocalView.current
    val prevScrollPosition = currentView.bottom
    var keyboardSize by remember{ mutableStateOf(0)}

    currentView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
        if (lazyListState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.isNotEmpty()) {
            val currentScreenSize = currentView.bottom
            if (currentScreenSize != actualScreenSize) { // keyboard is visible
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    delay(200)
                    if (keyboardHeight == 0){
                        keyboardHeight = actualScreenSize - currentScreenSize
                    }
                    lazyListState.animateScrollBy(keyboardHeight.toFloat())
                }
            }else {
                // keyboard is not visible
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here, whenever keyboard becomes visible we scroll `LazyColumn` up by keyboard height and whenever keyboard becomes invisible scroll `LazyColumn` down by keyboard height